# Working out the total number of combinations, with variations.

Tags: combinations

Hi there i am trying to work out the total possible number of combinations for a music system i have created. The system has 4 different instruments with each instruments having a varying number of variations.

Instrument 1 = 2 variations.
Instrument 2 = 3 variations.
Instrument 3 = 2 variations.
instrument 4 = 3 variations.

The only way i could think to do this is times them all together resulting in 36 is this correct?

Comment: Assuming that every instrument is used exactly once, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Correct! When you have independent events $e_1, e_2, ..., e_n$ and $N(e_k)$ gives the number of options for event $e_k$, the total number of combinations for events $e_1$ through $e_n$ is given by $$\prod_{k=1}^n N(e_k)$$

In other words, yes, you just multiply them together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In general, if process $1$ can be done in $m$ ways, and process $2$ can be done in $n$ ways, then the number of ways to do both processes is $m\times n$. This formula extends to any finite number of processes, so in this case, you just calculate: $$2\times 3\times 2\times 3=36,$$

as you did.